# How do you signal sync multiple flash video players with one FLV without having different timeframes?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash

I'm trying to create a simulation of a product. Currently I'm using flash CS4 to build the simulator.

I have two main monitor screens (default flash players)

then I have five little video monitors on the bottoms that are playing as if they are a live streaming feed.

The videos are local .FLV files stored in the same file as the swf.

What I want to accomplish is have the five video players start to play when the .swf is started, then when I press a button to select which one of the five little videos I want to play it displays it on the main two bigger video players. The only thing is I want to make sure that when I click on the button with the little video, the main display video plays the pick up of the timeline of the little video window. In other words I want the little window playing the video automatically, when I click on the button for the big window player to active and pick one of the little window videos that is play it be synced already.

This is what the wireframe looks like, the :

---

---------      ----------
|       |      |        |
|       |      |        |
---------     -----------

---  ---  ---   ---   ---
| |  | |  |  |  |  |  |  |
---  ---  ---   ---   ---

---

Or instead of using .flv file name, do I have to run a streaming server and tell the player to play the IP?

If anyone can point me to the right direction that would be great.

thanks,
joey

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes: You will need a [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), since a) you can't run the same Flash app on all of those monitors at once, so you can't sync within the app, and b) there is simply no way to synchronize across more than one player instance - except if you connect all the clients to the same Flash Media Server instance, open the same NetStream, and triggering playback by listening to some sort of synchronization event sent by the master client.

Comment: Hi weltraumpirat, Thank you for the suggestion, do you have links to download what is needed or a forum I can visit to gather all the tools needed? It's a bit of a learning curve for me. Open source would be great.

Comment: I've added a link to the adobe download site.  I'm afraid it's a commercial product, but there is a test version of the FMS you can download and use for free, so you won't need to invest any money until you know how to do things.  The site also has a couple of how-to manuals which I recommend you should read.  When I first started out with the server, I spent a lot of time in forums - that and reading the manuals helped quite a bit.